# Composite Query - Use limit param on GET REST API

Tags: rest-api, composite

I'm trying to use the Salesforce REST API in order to get an OrderSummary sObject using its ID.

With the following query `/composite/sobjects/:SOBJECT_API_NAME?ids=1Os1q0000004FpWCAU&fields=BillingAddress` everything run smooth and this is the result:

```
    {
        "attributes": {
            "type": "OrderSummary",
            "url": "/services/data/v54.0/sobjects/OrderSummary/1Os1q0000004FpWCAU"
        },
        "BillingAddress": {
            "city": "Torino",
            "country": "IT",
            "geocodeAccuracy": null,
            "latitude": null,
            "longitude": null,
            "postalCode": "10098",
            "state": "TO",
            "street": "Via Roma 99"
        },
        "Id": "1Os1q0000004FpWCAU"
    }
]
```

However, in case I need all the OrderSummary fields this is the written query `/composite/sobjects/:SOBJECT_API_NAME?ids=1Os1q0000004FpWCAU&fields=fields(all)` which returns the following error:

```
[
    {
        "message": "The SOQL FIELDS function must have a LIMIT of at most 200",
        "errorCode": "MALFORMED_QUERY"
    }
]
```

Is it possible to add the limit param inside the retrieve flow in order to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't look like you can add a `limit` here.

[The relevant documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections_retrieve.htm) states that the only parameters are `ids` and `fields`.

If you want to use `FIELDS(ALL)`, then it looks like you need to use the `query` resource. e.g. `/services/data/v55.0/query/?q=SELECT+FIELDS(ALL)+FROM+OderSummary+WHERE+Id+%3D+%271Os1q0000004FpWCAU%27`

%3D = `=`
%27 = `'`

No `+LIMIT+200` required with the query resource since Salesforce knows that the query won't return more than 200 records (though it's unclear why the `/composite/sobjects` resource can't internally do the same).

Comment: That feels like a bug, if you ask me.